# cannot print on network printer HP P1606DN

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, network-printer

At a working place, I have an HP 1606DN printer, connected directly to the network with a CAT5 cable.

All PCs (all with Windows 10) use the printer witouth problems, except one. This PC had it working, but one day it stopped.

The PC can ping to the printer, and it answers. It is also detected and installed by the HP driver, and by windows 10 "add printer tool -I specified the IP of the printer-) but it fails to print.

The network is a domain network. I checked the problem with the domain administrator, and he has absolutely no clue on why it shouldn't work.

I cannot access the printer webpage with a web browser.

I tried disabling windows 10 firewall, and had no effect on the problem.

I have no idea on how to diagnose what could possibly be the problem

Comment: Download and install "Print and Scan Doctor" run it and see if it can help solve the issue....https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02073861?jumpid=ex_r4155/hho/ipg/ccdoc/trailhead_doc

Comment: @Moab I did, but it did nothing. can't even print a test page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try the following ways to troubleshoot or resolve the issue:

First check the IP address of the printer? If it is consistent with the IP address we pinged?

1. If it is an IP address automatically assigned by the DHCP Server, this IP address may change. If it is not consistent with the IP address we pinged, the IP address of the printer is changed, we need to change the IP address of the network printer.
2. If it is consistent with the IP address we pinged. Then we turn off the network printer and ping its IP address, it should be not ping normally. If we can ping its IP address, it means that other devices on the network are using this IP address.Then we need to view the real IP of the network printer.
3. All of the above checks, after determining the IP address of the printer, and we can ping this IP address. If we still can't print now, delete the printer on our computer and re-add this network printer according to the printer's instructions.

We also need to go to the HP official website to download the printer driver of this model, and then install the network printer.

**How to change IP address of printer**

Step one:Installing wired network driver

Method 1:

The HP Smart Install driver, only Windows system supports this type of installation.
Check the IP Address on the configuration page.  On the computer to install the product, open the Web browser. In the browser's address line, type the IP address of the product. 
Click the tag of HP Smart Install, and then click the Download button.Run the downloaded driver and follow the instructions on the screen to complete the installation process.

Method 2:

Use random CD to install driver.Insert the software installation CD into the computer CD driver.If the installation program is not automatically opened, please browse the contents of CD SETUP.EXE and run the file. Set up products and install software according to the instructions on the screen.

Note: ensure that when prompted, select "configure to print through the network".

Step two: configure the network settings

Use the embedded Web server to view or change the configuration settings of IP.
The specific steps are as follows: look at the configuration page and find the address IP. If you use IPv4, then the IP address contains only numbers.The format is: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx . If you use IPv6, then the IP address is a combination of sixteen character characters and numbers. Its format is similar to: xxxx:: xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx .
To open the embedded Web server, type product IP address in the Web browser address line. Click Networking or other tabs to get network information. You can change the settings as required.